# Material Design Lite fixed navigation row

Tags: javascript, css, navigationbar, material-design-lite

I am having problems modifying the template for the [Android page](http://www.getmdl.io/templates/android-dot-com/index.html) provided as example(code can be found [here](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/tree/master/templates/android-dot-com)). I want to make the navigation bar on top transparent. The problem is there is nothing behind it, so it does not really change. The fix would be to make the navigation bar part of the page. As you can see currently the scrolling bar starts after the navigation bar, while I would like to make the navigation bar be part of the scrollable part of the page. I tried removing all relevant mdl header classes from the HTML which resulted to no effect. I found out that material.min.js (provided as part of MDL) makes the navigation stick on top of scroll bar but I am not very good at JS and I am not sure which part I need to modify to achieve what I want. I am also open to a solution that does not modify material.min.js but uses a custom JS/CSS.

Answer (score 1):

A little help to you.

Same matter happened to me. For a fixed navigation bar which will stick on the top you can do a little trick to the material.css file.

Change the .mdl-layout__header class from

```
.mdl-layout__header { display: -webkit-box;display: -webkit-flex;display:ms-flexbox;display: flex;-webkit-box-orient: vertical;-webkit-box-direction: normal;-webkit-flex-direction: column; and goes on
```

to

```
.mdl-layout__header {position : fixed;  display: -webkit-box;  display: -webkit-flex;  display: -ms-flexbox;  display: flex;  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  -webkit-box-direction: normal;  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
```

The added property is `position : fixed;` to the mdl-layout__header class

Hope this helps :)